# How to use function in callback of image onload event in react js?

Tags: reactjs

If i used `setState` or any other functions in `image.onload` callback then i got error like `this is not function`. And if i used local variable to handle error then condition was checked before value of local variable will be updated in `image.onload`.

```
handleProductImage = (e) => {
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let  height, width, isError = false;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function (file) {
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = file.target.result;
      img.onload = function () {
        height = this.height;
        width = this.width;
        if (height && width) {
          if (height < 250 || width < 250) {
             //--Use local variable---//
             //isError = true;
            //---Use setState for handle error---//
            // this.setState({ isError: true });
            //---Call function directly---//
            this.props.setErrorMessage();
          }
          else {
            //--Use local variable---//
            //isError = false;
            //---Use setState for handle error---//
            // this.setState({ isError: false });
            //---Call function directly---//
             this.handleImageCropper(e)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    //Use local variable for function call 
    //if (isError) {
      //console.log("error");
      //this.props.setErrorMessage();
    //}
    //else {
      //this.handleImageCropper(e)
    //}
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `this` and sometimes assume it's the image but later assume it is the component. Try the following:

```
handleProductImage = (e) => {
  const me = this;
  let file = e.target.files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();
  let height,
    width,
    isError = false;
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = function (file) {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = file.target.result;
    img.onload = function () {
      height = this.height;//leave "this" if you mean img.height
      width = this.width;
      if (height && width) {
        if (height < 250 || width < 250) {
          me.props.setErrorMessage();
        } else {
          me.handleImageCropper(e);
        }
      }
    };
  };
};
```